# Slopes not working in Phaser using arcade physics

Tags: javascript, csv, tiles, phaser-framework, tiled

I'm currently having this issue when I am trying to get a sprite to go up a slope within phaser using the phaser-arcade-slopes.min.js plugin. I am using a .csv tilemap also with a tile size of 32x32. I'm unsure if my names are just incorrect or I am using the wrong type of file for the tilemap itself. I have been getting errors such as - Tilemap.createLayer: Invalid layer ID given: null & Cannot read property 'resizeWorld' of undefined(…). Any help would be much appreciated.
"snow_tiles_32.png" is the name of the tileset I created and I'm using
"tiles.csv" the tilemap created inside Tiled.

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, '', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update });

function preload() {
this.game.load.tilemap('tilemap', 'assets/tilemaps/csv/tiles.csv', null, Phaser.Tilemap.CSV);
this.game.load.spritesheet('tiles', 'assets/tilemaps/tiles/snow_tiles_32.png', 32,32);
this.game.load.spritesheet('player', 'assets/penguin.png', 32,48);
}

var player;
var cursors;

function create() {
this.game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
this.game.plugins.add(Phaser.Plugin.ArcadeSlopes);
cursors = game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

this.map = this.game.add.tilemap('tilemap');
this.map.addTilesetImage('snow_tiles_32', 'tiles');

this.game.stage.backgroundColor = '#80e3ff';

this.ground = this.map.createLayer('collision');
this.ground.resizeWorld();

this.game.slopes.convertTilemapLayer(this.ground,{
    2:  'FULL',
    3:  'HALF_BOTTOM_LEFT',
    4:  'HALF_BOTTOM_RIGHT',
    6:  'HALF_TOP_LEFT',
    5:  'HALF_TOP_RIGHT',
    15: 'QUARTER_BOTTOM_LEFT_LOW',
    16: 'QUARTER_BOTTOM_RIGHT_LOW',
    17: 'QUARTER_TOP_RIGHT_LOW',
    18: 'QUARTER_TOP_LEFT_LOW',
    19: 'QUARTER_BOTTOM_LEFT_HIGH',
    20: 'QUARTER_BOTTOM_RIGHT_HIGH',
    21: 'QUARTER_TOP_RIGHT_HIGH',
    22: 'QUARTER_TOP_LEFT_HIGH',
    23: 'QUARTER_LEFT_BOTTOM_HIGH',
    24: 'QUARTER_RIGHT_BOTTOM_HIGH',
    25: 'QUARTER_RIGHT_TOP_LOW',
    26: 'QUARTER_LEFT_TOP_LOW',
    27: 'QUARTER_LEFT_BOTTOM_LOW',
    28: 'QUARTER_RIGHT_BOTTOM_LOW',
    29: 'QUARTER_RIGHT_TOP_HIGH',
    30: 'QUARTER_LEFT_TOP_HIGH',
    31: 'HALF_BOTTOM',
    32: 'HALF_RIGHT',
    33: 'HALF_TOP',
    34: 'HALF_LEFT'
});

this.map.setCollisionBetween(2,34, true, 'collision');

//player
this.player = this.game.add.sprite(100,50,'player');
this.game.physics.arcade.enable(player);

this.player.body.bounce.y = 0.2;
this.player.body.gravity.y = 2000;
this.player.body.collideWorldBounds = true;

this.player.animations.add('left', [0,1,2,3], 10, true);
this.player.animations.add('right', [5,6,7,8], 10, true);
this.game.slopes.enable(this.player);
this.game.camera.follow(this.player);

}

function update() {

this.game.physics.arcade.collide(this.player, this.ground);

this.player.body.velocity.x = 0;

if(cursors.left.isDown){
    this.player.body.velocity.x = -150;
    this.player.animations.play('left');
}
else if (cursors.right.isDown){
    this.player.body.velocity.x = 150;
    this.player.animations.play('right');
}
else{
    this.player.animations.stop();
    this.player.frame = 4;
}

if(cursors.up.isDown && player.body.onFloor()){
    this.player.body.velocity.y = -350;
}
```

}

Comment: use this plugin plugin https://github.com/hexus/phaser-arcade-slopes

Answer (score 0):

LayerID you provide as parameter for createLayer() must match map layer defined in map file, see [documentation](https://phaser.io/docs/2.6.2/Phaser.Tilemap.html#createLayer). So my best guess would be to open map file in tiled once again and check what layer names you have.

Additionally there's example how to use .csv files (here)[http://phaser.io/examples/v2/tilemaps/csv-map].

Hope that'll help somehow.